# how to send the gridview in email with formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gridview

I am developing an online ordering web application in which I have to email with perches product details to customer. I have maintain all the data in a data table and then generated the grid view pragmatically as follows

```
 public GridView makeGridview(DataTable Dt)
        {
            GridView GV = new GridView();
            GV.DataSource = Dt;
            GV.DataBind();
            return GV;
        }
```

then adding this grid view to email

```
 body = body.Replace("{Product_Details}", GridViewToHtml(makeGridview(Dt)));

private string GridViewToHtml(GridView gv)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(hw);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

This is working fine but the problem is then am unable to design it in our predefine format. This mail will be received by the customer of my website, so I need to convert in to our them.
Please guide me how to format in our them.

If there is an another way to do this then I'm open to that as well.

Comment: Export the HTML table (`RenderControl`) and send

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to not trust the GridView as your rendered html, but instead to use your current data-source for that (DataTable):

```
    public GridView CreateHtmlTable(DataTable dt)
    {
       //Do your HTML work here, like the following:
       string tab = "\t";

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       sb.AppendLine("<html>");
       sb.AppendLine(tab + "<body>");
       sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "<table>");

       // headers.
       sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

       foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
       {        
       sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", dc.ColumnName);        
       }

       sb.AppendLine("</tr>");

       // data rows
       foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
       {
                  sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        string cellValue = dr[dc] != null ? dr[dc].ToString() : "";
        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", cellValue);
    }

    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
}

       sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "</table>");
       sb.AppendLine(tab + "</body>");
       sb.AppendLine("</html>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow follwing code:**

```
public void SendHTMLMail()
{
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("administrator@aspdotnet-suresh.com");
// Sender e-mail address.
Msg.From = fromMail;
// Recipient e-mail address.
Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("suresh@gmail.com"));
// Subject of e-mail
Msg.Subject = "Send Gridivew in EMail";
Msg.Body += "Please check below data <br/><br/>";
Msg.Body += GetGridviewData(gvUserInfo);
Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
string sSmtpServer = "";
sSmtpServer = "10.2.160.101";
SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient();
a.Host = sSmtpServer;
a.EnableSsl = true;
a.Send(Msg);
}
// This Method is used to render gridview control
public string GetGridviewData(GridView gv)
{
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder);
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

**Refer below doccument:**

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/how-to-send-gridview-in-email-body-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Honestly what you have done here (rendering a Web Forms control to an email string) seems like a bit of an unintended trick.  Honestly it's not that hard to iterate through a collection and build an HTML table using a StringBuilder.

I believe that for email HTML the convention is often to use inline styles to guarantee the best compatibility with email clients.  So you'd want to style your elements like so:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: #EE0000">
      <td style="text-transform: uppercase"></td>
      ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the past I've done this by creating an HTML file with everything how I want it and using placeholders like `{VariableName}` and then doing a string replace on the variables with their values.  This way you separate your HTML view from the C# code.  It'd be a little tricky with a list of items, in that case you'd have at least two HTML templates: one for the entire document and one for the item rows.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue like yours, and I got it done like this:

- encapsulated the functionality in a separate HelperClass for ease of use. Used static variables and methods to keep it simple
- write the HTML code to format the content of the GridView to a nice table (with zebra stripes and stuffs)

  ```
   public static StringBuilder gridViewToHTML(GridView gv)
  {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      sb.AppendLine("<html>");
      sb.AppendLine("<body>");
      sb.AppendLine(@"<table style='padding: 10px; font-family: Verdana; font-size:11px;
                          border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:grey;'> ");

      sb.AppendLine("<tr>");

      /* *** Build header of the HTML table *** */
      for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
      {
          sb.AppendLine("<td style='font-weight:bold;background-color:black;color:white;'>" + gv.Columns[i].HeaderText + "</td>");
      }

      sb.AppendLine("</tr>");



      /* *** Build body of the HTML table *** */
      for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
          sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
          foreach (DataControlFieldCell gvcell in gv.Rows[i].Cells)
          {
              sb.AppendLine("<td style='text-align;left;'>" + gvcell.ToString() + "</td>");
          }
          sb.AppendLine("</tr");
      }



      sb.AppendLine("</table>");
      sb.AppendLine("</body>");
      sb.AppendLine("</html>");

      return sb;
  }
  ```
- send the email message using the StringBuilder object as html formatting of the content, and the casual parameters (to Whom, and Subject)

  ```
   public static void sendEmailMessage(StringBuilder stringBuilder, string email_ToAddress, string email_Subject)
  {
      DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
      DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
      //SomeEmailAccount@yourOrganization.com    must be set by your Sysadmin before using it.
      mail.From = new MailAddress("SomeEmailAccount@yourOrganization.com");
      mail.To.Add(email_ToAddress);

      mail.Subject = $"{email_Subject} . Date #{now.ToShortDateString()}";
      mail.Body = stringBuilder.ToString();
      mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

      NetworkCredential autentificare = new NetworkCredential();
      autentificare.UserName = "SomeEmailAccount@yourOrganization.com"";
      autentificare.Password = "yourPassw0rd";

      SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

      smtp.Host = "mail.yourOrganization.com";
      smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
      smtp.Credentials = autentificare;
      smtp.Port = 25;
      smtp.EnableSsl = false;
      smtp.Send(mail);

  }
  ```